# How to make active both the header button and the listed button?

Tags: php

First of all, apoligise for the messy title, I could not came up with a better one. You will understand the question better in the code. When I click in Private University I can make that button active, but I either want to make active the button Study Opportunity. Thanks.

```
<li class="dropdown <?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'study-opportunity.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>">
                  <a href="study-opportunity.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Study Opportunity<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'universitetet-me-konkurim.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="universitetet-me-konkurim.php">Universitetet me Konkurim</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'private-university.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="private-university.php">Private University</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'studime-jashte-vendit.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="studime-jashte-vendit.php">Studime Jashte Vendit</a></li>
                    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'bursa.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="bursa.php">Bursa Studimi</a></li>               
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your problem. It's quite difficult to understand from the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check all of the links in the dropdown too:

```
<li class="dropdown <?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'study-opportunity.php' || basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'universitetet-me-konkurim.php' || basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'private-university.php' || basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'studime-jashte-vendit.php' || basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'bursa.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>">
<a href="study-opportunity.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Study Opportunity<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'universitetet-me-konkurim.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="universitetet-me-konkurim.php">Universitetet me Konkurim</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'private-university.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="private-university.php">Private University</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'studime-jashte-vendit.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="studime-jashte-vendit.php">Studime Jashte Vendit</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'bursa.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="bursa.php">Bursa Studimi</a></li>               
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: haha never tried the 'or' thing (completely idiot :P), thanks for the help